# Best way to grab a single value from a table?

Tags: c#, database, linq, asp.net-web-api

So I have a method designed to grab a single value from the table using a key that may or may not be in the table. My method looks like this, after changing some names around.

Using Entity Framework and Linq

```
public IHttpActionResult GetBool(int Id)
{
    Entity e = db.Entity.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id== Id);

    if (e == null) return NotFound();

    return Ok(e.BoolValue);
}
```

This call seems unnecessary, pulling the whole entire Entity just to address one value. How do I error check for the entity possibly not existing while at the same time only grabbing the relevant columns?

My solution is something like

```
bool value =
            (from e in db.Entity
            where e.ID == Id
            select e.BoolValue).ToList().ElementAtOrDefault(0);
if(value== null) return NotFound();
return Ok(value);
```

Is this the best way to query?

**Solution:**

Top Answer:

```
return db.Entity.Where(x => x.Id== Id)
                .Select(x => Ok(x.BoolValue))
                .DefaultIfEmpty(NotFound())
                .First();
```

For my personal needs, I modified it to return as a JSON object.

Comment: What is `NotFound` and `Ok` and `disabled` and what type is `BoolValue`? Also, why is a single record _heavy_?

Comment: Changed my question to fix the typo in value and also to not say heavy and expensive, but rather to say unnecessary. I was merely asking what the best way to do this was. As for what is NotFound and Ok, these are status codes and provided by asp.net web api, not methods I made myself. And sorry, I thought it was evident BoolValue was just a value stored inside Entity that is a bool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could select this column and specify a default value:

```
return db.Entity.Where(x => x.Id== Id)
    .Select(x => Ok(x.BoolValue))
    .DefaultIfEmpty(NotFound())
    .First();
```

However, selecting a single record and return one of it's columns isn't really expensive. If it's causing a performance issue you should better fetch multiple records with one query instead of always executing `GetBool` in a loop.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Expensive was not the correct word. I edited to make it say "unnecessary" instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
var value = (from e in db.Entity
             where e.ID == Id
             select e.BoolValue).SingleOrDefault();
if(value == null) 
    return NotFound();
else 
    return Ok(value);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Hey @ryanyuyu , the context makes sense to me in regards to the context. The query will grab the value, SingleOrDefault() guarantees that it will only return one value or null if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @LordHoneydew [Code-only answer are frowned upon](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290231/is-it-wrong-to-ask-for-a-description-of-how-why-the-code-works-in-code-only-answ).  This one is at least readable, but explanation does improve the quality of the post (as seen by [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34205252/4320665) which offers more explanation).